# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() python fix this?

Tags: python

How can i fix this........ full code is below it should search for all members of a form and eventually print them and save them to a csv file

```
import csv
import time


def main():
    myList = [ ]
    myList = read_csv()
    ##myList = showList(myList)
    searchList = searchQueryForm(myList)
    if searchList:
        showList(searchList)
    else:
            print("I have nothing to print")




    if len(searchList) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

have no idea what it means can anyone fix this..

neeed this asap

Comment: Well the error is pretty self-explanatory your searchList is invalid so is `None` object

Comment: You could change: `if len(searchList)==0:` to `if not searchList:`

Answer (score 1):

This means that your `searchQueryForm` function returns `None`. You can either change it to return an empty list (`[]`) if this is more appropiate, or change your condition checking the result like this:

```
if not searchList:
    print("I have nothing to print")
else:
    showList(searchList)
```

This will check if the `searchList` variable is either `None` or empty ([explanation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)).

If having a result is the expected way this is to go, I would recommend to flip the conditions. Positive conditions are usually easier to understand when reading the code:

```
if searchList:
    showList(searchList)
else:
    print("I have nothing to print")
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that your searchList is empty. The function searchQueryForm is probably resulting in empty object. You can try to print and see